# AWS: Start-up launch servers (Node.js + Postgres)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-opsworks, aws-aurora-serverless, aws-billing

We're getting ready to launch our iOS app and our backend is on `Node.js` and `Postgres` database.

We plan to use `Aurora Postgresql` for storage (text only, no pictures).

Currently, we have an `EC2` development server `t2.small` that I reserved for `36 months` (`All upfront`) and it works great.  This server doubles as a `Node.js` + `Postgres` on `Ubuntu`.

We would like to go into production in North America (U.S. and Canada) only.  We have 0 users right now.  We'd be lucky if we can get 10 users in the next 30-90 days.  Each user may use the app for 5-10min a couple of times a week.

Question:  I am not sure what size servers I should go with.  I would like to save money and happy to pay `All Upfront`; however, I am not sure:

1. What size and how many servers I should use for `Node.js` when reserving?
2. What size and how many servers I should use to reserve for `Aurora Postgres`.  Should we go Serverless?
3. How often should I backup my DB and what's a good practice to save money here.
4. What regions should I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can start with t2.small and then [scale up](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html) the instance if it is bogging down
2. Since you currently have no users, and only expect the 10 future users to be on for a few minutes a couple times per week, I would recommend going with serverless (you have to select Postgres 10.7), setting it to [pause after (at least) 5 minutes of inactivity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.modifying.html), if your use case can tolerate a 30-second(ish) cold-start delay when the user first attempts to access the database. You can pre-warm the database by sending it an empty query `";"` as soon as the user logs in to the app, which could make the cold-start invisible from the user's point of view. If your use-case can't tolerate a cold start, you can have it [scale down](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.create.html) to 1 ACU when inactive rather than pausing.
3. Aurora serverless does daily backups automatically, for the duration between 1 and 35 days that suits your risk tolerance.
4. Consider us-east-2 for a (mostly) central location if your users are all over the US and Canada.

Comment: Thanks!  I don’t think we can tolerate a 30ish cold start. Client is iOS so the Database should be available all the time.

Comment: Is there a way to conserve cost while having the DB available all the time?

Comment: @user1107173 Added a sentence to #2 that describes a method for minimizing cost while having the DB available all the time.